# Spring security client PKCE with Keycloak

Tags: java, spring-security, keycloak, pkce

I have a Java application using Spring Security 5.2.1 and secured by Keycloak.
The client in Keycloak is a public openid-connect client.
It works fine.

I have now a requirement to use PKCE (Proof Key for Code Exchange).
As Client Support for PKCE has been added to Spring Security 5.2.0.M2 and as I use Spring Security 5.2.1, I can use Spring Security to implement it.
That's the good news.
The 'bad' news is that I found nearly nothing on the Web or in the Spring Security documentation on how I must implement it, practically.
Adding "enable-pkce": true in keycloak.json doesn't work, and I don't find any clear example of what to do.

Is there some documentation, website or whatever else, describing what to do to implementsthis ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Are you wondering how to implement this in the Spring client?

Comment: Yes, in the Spring client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Spring Security reference documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.1.RELEASE/reference/html5/#initiating-the-authorization-request

> PKCE will automatically be used when the following conditions are true:
>
> 1. `client-secret` is omitted (or empty)
> 2. `client-authentication-method` is set to "none" (`ClientAuthenticationMethod.NONE`)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm not sure I understand.
I just set enable-pkce in my keycloak.json, that's all I changed. 
When I set PKE to S256 on my Keycloak client, my application doesn't work anymore, it loops forever while trying to redirect (HTTP 302) and in the Keycloak logs, I see a lot of this :

(message in the next comment, no space anymore)

Comment: INFO  [org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.endpoints.AuthorizationEndpoint] (default task-32) PKCE enforced Client without code challenge method.
WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-32) type=LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=someRealmId, clientId=someClientId, userId=null, ipAddress=11.11.11.11, error=invalid_request, response_type=code, redirect_uri=https://localhost/xxx/sso/login, response_mode=query

Comment: One more information, I use Keycloak Spring Security adapter